# Why would they say in Star Trek TOS Day of the Dove it was dangerous to beam intra-ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In Star Trek TOS S03:E07 [Day of the Dove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dove) it is said to be dangerous to beam intra-ship.

Yet in [TNG](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) it is common. We even see intra-ship beaming in Star Trek Discovery [S1:E08](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Si_Vis_Pacem,_Para_Bellum_(episode)) *Si Vis Pacem, Para Bellum*.

My question is: **Why would they say in TOS it was dangerous to beam intra-ship?**

Comment: Because the technology in TNG is a hundred years more advanced?

Comment: And Discovery was produced 50 years after TOS

Comment: Only a fool beams in a burning house.

Comment: For the same reason they didn't use shuttlecraft to rescue the landing party in The Enemy Within?

Comment: TNG is 100 years later. Technology has changed. Memory Alpha give the launch date of the Enterprise NCC 1701 as 2245 while it says that in 2256 Discovery was still considered "new.. and equipped with some of Starfleets most advanced technologies" as in, it's better than a 10 year old heavy cruiser.

Comment: When a hostile alien controls the ship as in "Day of the Dove", it may be able to divert the transporter beam.

Comment: Thanks @geewhiz - could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: I would but most of my answer would come from memory alpha as I have not seen beyond the first episode of Discovery. If someone here watches the show and wants to use my comment as a basis for their answer, go nuts.

Comment: Transporter capabilities seemed to ebb and flow. No fear of materializing safely on any planet, in buildings, aboard other ships or under ground (A Piece of the Action, The Tholian Web, The Omega Glory, The Doomsday Machine, The Cloud Minders), and yet it was tricky/hazardous too ("just don't put me inside a bulkhead" The Enterprise Incident, Day of the Dove)

Answer (score 1):

As far as canon (excluding Discovery, as I haven't watched it yet), Transporter technology was much more advanced in the 24th century than in Kirk's time.  They are able to beam around the ship (as the plot desires).

I have no clue why they would be able to do that in *Discovery*